# Kafka consumer subscribers -- member assignments being lost (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, strimzi, kafkajs

#### Synopsis

We have a subscriber that responds to events on 5 topics with a single consumer-group, each with a single partition. When firing events into these topics, we see our code handling the first two events, then nothing. When we check, on startup, the consumer group has 5 member assignments, but after handling the 2nd event *all* of the member assignments disappear.

#### Code

Here is the subscription code:

```js
  connectoToConsumer: async () => {
    const groupId = `${Group}-adaptor`;
    log.debug({ msg: `Connecting to event consumer...`, groupId });
    _app.connection.consumer = _app.kafka.consumer({ groupId });
    await _app.connection.consumer.connect();
  },

  subscribe: async topics => {
    log.debug("Subscribing to many topics...");
    for (const topic of topics.split(",")) {
      await _app.subscribeConsumerToTopic(topic);
    }
  },

  subscribeConsumerToTopic: async topic => {
    log.debug({ msg: "Subscribing to topic", topic });
    try {
      await _app.connection.consumer.subscribe({ topic: topic, fromBeginning: false });
    } catch (e) {
      log.error({ msg: `FATAL ERROR: Event adaptor consumer connection failed`, type: "error", subtype: "fatal", source: "registerConsumer", cause: e });
      process.kill(process.pid, "SIGINT");
    }
  },

  runConsumer: async () => {
    await _app.connection.consumer.run({
      autoCommitInterval: 100,
      autoCommitThreshold: 100,
      eachMessage: async ({ ignore_topic, ignore_partition, message: event }) => handler(event)
    });
  },
```

To invoke this we use:

```js
await _app.connectoToConsumer();
await _app.subscribe(topics);
await _app.runConsumer();
```

#### Output

When we run the consumer we see a log message from kafka:

```json
{
  "level": "INFO",
  "timestamp": "2022-04-21T11:23:30.186Z",
  "logger": "kafkajs",
  "message": "[ConsumerGroup] Consumer has joined the group",
  "groupId": "service-invoice.projection.1-adaptor",
  "memberId": "ctx-service-invoice.projection.1-adaptor-f3ff61a9-9d21-4aeb-9560-ba415188cacd-3914c6d0-6674-4342-8a45-8114c3cd6b62",
  "leaderId": "ctx-service-invoice.projection.1-adaptor-f3ff61a9-9d21-4aeb-9560-ba415188cacd-3914c6d0-6674-4342-8a45-8114c3cd6b62",
  "isLeader": true,
  "memberAssignment": {
    "service-invoice.created.1": [
      0
    ],
    "service-invoice.approved.1": [
      0
    ],
    "service-invoice.service-orders-created.1": [
      0
    ],
    "service-invoice.service-orders-invoiced.1": [
      0
    ],
    "service-invoice.customer-changed.1": [
      0
    ]
  },
  "groupProtocol": "RoundRobinAssigner",
  "duration": 23555
}
```

Showing that we have successfully subscribed to 5 topics. We expect to see those 5 events in the order listed above. However, after the `approve` event, no other events are handled, and when we look at kafka all the members have gone. There is no exception or other log that would suggest an error in our code.

Incidentally, our handlers run very fast. They make a local HTTP call to another container in the same pod that updates a single field in a single document in MongoDB. Typically the handlers run and respond in < 500ms.

#### Suspicions

As JavaTechnical suggests in the answer below, we believe that this may be related to the heartbeat mechanism. The kafka logs show this:

```
2022-04-21 13:17:56,941 INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Member ctx-service-invoice.projection.1-adaptor-4b32ab43-17f2-4b98-84ed-b21ee36b771f-d6040fbd-2fb8-4025-9fdd-5fb8fb6b41a1 in group service-invoice.projection.1-adaptor has failed, removing it from the group (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator) [executor-Heartbeat]
```

We're using strimzi to run kafka in k8s, and we see in the logs:

```
broker.heartbeat.interval.ms = 2000
broker.session.timeout.ms = 9000
group.max.session.timeout.ms = 1800000
group.min.session.timeout.ms = 6000
```

We think that the consumption of the first two messages is probably just luck -- we're getting them before the session-timeout is triggered by the lack of heartbeats.

#### What have we tried?

We tried setting the heartbeat interval in our kafkajs code:

```js
.connection.consumer = _app.kafka.consumer({ groupId, , heartbeatInterval: 1000 });
```

But that isn't helping.

- Kafkajs documentation says that the `eachMessage` structure in the consumer runner should automate the heartbeats, but given the nature of the error we've also tried explicitly passing the heartbeat function to the handler and manually invoking it, also to no avail.
- We've also tried extending the timeouts and heartbeat intervals using strimzi, but our attempts to do so failed (they crashed strimzi) so we've backed out of that.

#### Question

Given all of this, we suspect that the kafkajs heartbeats are not making it through to kafka in k8s. Our question is, how do we ensure that this works?

#### Versions

We're using the latest strimzi, kafka, and kafkajs in node 17+.

Comment: As recommended by Confluent, we have reimplemented this service using node-rdkafka and the problem has magically disappeared. Therefore, we suspect this to be some kind of bug in kafjaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When we check, on startup, the consumer group has 5 member
> assignments, but after handling the 2nd event all of the member
> assignments disappear.

If the members are not there in the group means they are kicked-off.
This happens when your consumers are not able to send heartbeats either because they are down or because they are taking long time to send their heartbeats. Possible ways to debug:

1. See if there is any network issue.
2. See if your handler is taking long time than the configured session timeout.

From the kafkajs documentation..

> Be aware that the eachMessage handler should not block for longer than
> the configured session timeout or else the consumer will be removed
> from the group.

If no heartbeats are received within this `sessionTimeout`, your consumers will be kicked out of the group. The default is `30000ms`. Check if you have modified it (or) it is too less for what you do in your `handler()`

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. We stumbled upon similar suspicions about the same time you were writing this (because of the logs). Our handlers are fast, so its not that (and, besides, we're using the latest kafka where heartbeats are performed in a separate thread to the handler and so handler latency isn't relevant any more). We agree now that it is a heartbeat issue, so I suppose the question is why heartbeats are not making it through to kafka in our environment.

Comment: "Heartbeats are done in separate thread" - I am only aware of it being implemented in Java, does kafkajs also do this? Anyways, did you try calling `hearbeat()` manually?

Comment: I've just checked the kafkajs code and it calls heartbeat() correctly. I've updated the question with a 'what we've tried' section, and yeah, calling heartbeat manually was also tried. The problem seems to be that it is only called when there is an event being responded to.

Comment: I mean calling it separately in another thread and just leave the thread running, just to see if it is reaching the server and that the consumer remains in the group without getting kicked off.